# How can I calculate $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(nI_n)_{n\geq0}$ where $ I_n=\int_{0}^{1}x^{2004}\cos(nx)dx, n\in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

All I know is that  $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(I_n)_{n\geq0}=0$ if this helps in any way.

Comment: Why do you want to calculate the limit if you already know it?

Comment: I forgot to take out that troublesome n sitting before $I_n$. Thanks for pointing out the mistake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Integrating by parts with $u=x^{2004}$ and $v=\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}$ reveals

$$I_n=\frac{\sin(n)}{n}-\frac{2004}{n}\int_0^1 x^{2003}\sin(nx)\,dx$$

Then, we see that

$$nI_n=\sin(n)-2004\int_0^1 x^{2003}\sin(nx)\,dx \tag 1$$

The limit of the integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ approaches $0$ as $n\to \infty$.  Inasmuch as $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sin(n)$ fails to exist, the limit $\lim_{n\to \infty}nI_n$ fails to exist also.

Comment: +1. Stolz-Ces$\mathrm{\grave{a}}$ro doesn't seem very helpful in this case. Fine job.